# Neo4j Cypher query to find nodes that are not connected too slow

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

Given we have the following Neo4j schema (simplified but it shows the important point). There are two types of nodes `NODE` and `VERSION`. `VERSION`s are connected to `NODE`s via a `VERSION_OF` relationship. `VERSION` nodes do have two properties `from` and `until` that denote the validity timespan - either or both can be `NULL` (nonexistent in Neo4j terms) to denote *unlimited*. `NODE`s can be connected via a `HAS_CHILD` relationship. Again these relationships have two properties `from` and `until` that denote the validity timespan - either or both can be `NULL` (nonexistent in Neo4j terms) to denote *unlimited*.

**EDIT**: The validity dates on `VERSION` nodes and `HAS_CHILD` relations are independent (even though the example coincidentally shows them being aligned).

[image]

The example shows two `NODE`s **A** and **B**. **A** has two `VERSION`s **AV1** until 6/30/17 and **AV2** starting from 7/1/17 while **B** only has one version **BV1** that is unlimited. **B** is connected to **A** via a `HAS_CHILD` relationship until 6/30/17.

The challenge now is to query the graph for all nodes that aren't a **child** (that are root nodes) at one specific moment in time. Given the example above, the query should return just **B** if the query date is e.g. 6/1/17, but it should return **B** and **A** if the query date is e.g. 8/1/17 (because **A** isn't a child of **B** as of 7/1/17 any more).

The current query today is roughly similar to that one:

```
MATCH (n1:NODE)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n1)<-[c]-(n2:NODE), (n2)<-[:VERSION_OF]-(nv2:ITEM_VERSION)
WHERE (c.from <= {date} <= c.until)
AND (nv2.from <= {date} <= nv2.until)
WITH n1 WHERE c IS NULL 
MATCH (n1)<-[:VERSION_OF]-(nv1:ITEM_VERSION)
WHERE nv1.from <= {date} <= nv1.until
RETURN n1, nv1 
ORDER BY toLower(nv1.title) ASC 
SKIP 0 LIMIT 15
```

This query works relatively fine in general but it starts getting slow as hell when used on large datasets (comparable to real production datasets). With 20-30k `NODE`s (and about twice the number of `VERSION`s) the (real) query takes roughly 500-700 ms on a small docker container running on Mac OS X) which is acceptable. But with 1.5M `NODE`s (and about twice the number of `VERSION`s) the (real) query takes a little more than 1 minute on a bare-metal server (running nothing else than Neo4j). This is not really acceptable.

Do we have any option to tune this query? Are there better ways to handle the versioning of `NODE`s (which I doubt is the performance problem here) or the validity of relationships? I know that relationship properties cannot be indexed, so there might be a better schema for handling the validity of these relationships.

Any help or even the slightest hint is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT after [answer from Michael Hunger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41707737/11354):**

1. Percentage of root nodes:

   With the current example data set (1.5M nodes) the result set contains about 2k rows. That's less than 1%.
2. `ITEM_VERSION` node in first `MATCH`:

   We're using the `ITEM_VERSION` `nv2` to filter the result set to `ITEM` nodes that have no connection other `ITEM` nodes at the given date. That means that either no relationship must exist that is valid for the given date or the connected item must not have an `ITEM_VERSION` that is valid for the given date. I'm trying to illustrate this:

   ```
   // date 6/1/17

   // n1 returned because relationship not valid
   (nv1 ...)->(n1)-[X_HAS_CHILD ...6/30/17]->(n2)<-(nv2 ...)

   // n1 not returned because relationship and connected item n2 valid
   (nv1 ...)->(n1)-[X_HAS_CHILD ...]->(n2)<-(nv2 ...)

   // n1 returned because connected item n2 not valid even though relationship is valid
   (nv1 ...)->(n1)-[X_HAS_CHILD ...]->(n2)<-(nv2 ...6/30/17)
   ```
3. No use of relationship-types:

   The problem here is that the software features a user-defined schema and `ITEM` nodes are connected by custom relationship-types. As we can't have multiple types/labels on a relationship the only common characteristic for these kind of relationships is that they all start with `X_`. That's been left out of the simplified example here. Would searching with the predicate `type(r) STARTS WITH 'X_'` help here?

Comment: Is there any correlation between a :VERSION node's from and until dates, and the from and until dates on HAS_CHILD relationships? If they align, it may be better to have the relationship be to the relevant :VERSION nodes.

Comment: @InverseFalcon No. The "versioning" on relationships and nodes is independent. Perhaps the example isn't the best to illustrate this because the version validity for **AV1** coincidentally is the same as for the `HAS_CHILD` relation. But these can be arbitrary dates.

Comment: If you know which rel-types you want to search you can list them all explicitly, like `-[:X_FOO|:X_BAR*]->`

Comment: @MichaelHunger: Would that be better than an unrestricted search?  The approx. number of `X_` relationships is 13.5M, while total number of relationships is 19.5M - so about 70% of the relationships in the database are custom ones.

Comment: @MichaelHunger: If I add the all available labels, I get more db hits. Does that make any sense?

Answer (score 3):

What Neo4j version are you using.

What percentage of your 1.5M nodes will be found as roots at your example date, and if you don't have the limit how much data comes back? Perhaps the issue is not in the match so much as in the sorting at the end?

I'm not sure why you had the VERSION nodes in your first part, at least you don't describe them as relevant for determining a root node.

You didn't use relationship-types.

```
MATCH (n1:NODE) // matches 1.5M nodes
// has to do 1.5M * degree optional matches
OPTIONAL MATCH (n1)<-[c:HAS_CHILD]-(n2) WHERE (c.from <= {date} <= c.until)
WITH n1 WHERE c IS NULL
// how many root nodes are left?
// # root nodes * version degree (1..2)
MATCH (n1)<-[:VERSION_OF]-(nv1:ITEM_VERSION)
WHERE nv1.from <= {date} <= nv1.until
// has to sort all those
WITH n1, nv1, toLower(nv1.title) as title
RETURN n1, nv1
ORDER BY title ASC 
SKIP 0 LIMIT 15
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a good start for improvement would be to match on nodes using an index so you can quickly get a smaller relevant subset of nodes to search. Your approach right now must inspect all your :NODEs and all their relationships and patterns off of them every single time, which, as you've found, won't scale with your data.

Right now the only nodes in your graph with date/time properties are your :ITEM_VERSION nodes, so let's start with those. You'll need an index on :ITEM_VERSION's from and until properties for fast lookup.

The nulls are going to be problematic for your lookups, as any inequality against a null value returns null, and most workarounds to working with nulls (using COALESCE() or several ANDs/ORs for null cases) seem to prevent usage of index lookups, which is the point of my particular suggestion.

I would encourage you to replace your nulls in from and until with min and max values, which should let you take advantage of finding nodes by index lookup:

```
MATCH (version:ITEM_VERSION)
WHERE version.from <= {date} <= version.until
MATCH (version)<-[:VERSION_OF]-(node:NODE)
...
```

That should at least provide quick access to a smaller subset of nodes at the start for continuing your query.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your idea about the `ITEM_VERSION`-first approach seems reasonable. You're also right about indexing - that's already done. Same is true for the `from` and `until` properties - they use `0` and `9999123` as min and max values respectively. This allows for range scans with `version.from <= {date} <= version.until`. The dates are generally stored in this integer format (and not as date/time strings).