# Neo4j Cypher filtering relationships by weight on large scaled graph

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher, relationship, graph-databases

I have a question about how to efficiently filtering search results based on a property of a relationship.

---

I have a graph like this:

(:PERSON)-[:WORKED_WITH {weight:30}]->(:PERSON)

with over 300.000 nodes labeled PERSON and over 15.000.000 edges labeled :WORKED_WITH (each has an integer weight).

---

Now for example I want to have the 10 node combinations with the highest weight between them. So my query looks like this:

```
MATCH (n:PERSON)-[r:WORKED_WITH]->(m:PERSON)
RETURN n.name, m.name, r.weight
ORDER BY r.weight DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

As I recently read it is not possible to create an index on a property of a relationship. I read you could create nodes for partitions like <50, 50-100, >100 as an example, but that does not feel like best practise... Is there a possibility to use something that behaves like an (inequality) index? Or what would you suppose to solve this kind of problems efficient?

Regards
Wolfgang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stefan Armbruster explains the point (and your options) well in [How to create an index on a property of a relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31563680/how-to-create-an-index-on-a-property-of-a-relation).

If the relationship is the sole entrypoint into your graph (read: if there is no other way to reduce the initial search) ... then you may want to remodel it (as a node). That may indeed not "feel" correct, but it is best practice.

Hope this helps,
Tom

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I already read that post, but did not think it hits exactly my problem...

Comment: The problem is your entrypoint into the graph. If I understand your explanation well (correct me if not) the only determining factor is the property on the relationship. If so your options are limited (if you want things to be fast that is).

Comment: I don't want to change the data model for every new task... I thought of something like forcing Neo4j to sort internally based on this property... So I could easily say rel.weight > 50 or in between 30 and 50 .... I will later use a jaccard coefficient, which would be even harder to split ...

Comment: You are right ... In this case that is my only entrypoint into the graph

Comment: Understood (and I understand not wanting to remodel). Currently a manual index would be your best option then.

Comment: Thank you for your answer again, I was afraid you would say that... I just thought Neo4j might implemented something in this context in the last 2-3 years..

Comment: If you have not already, check https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_using_manual_index_on_relationship_properties.